# Collapse div/element on mobile screens only with Bootstrap

Tags: twitter-bootstrap, responsive-design

Is it possible to collapse a sidebar div - only on mobiles - using Bootstrap? How would I go about doing something like the example in the image? So that on a mobiles the sidebar collapses and when clicked, expands. I don't understand how media queries would allow me to do this becuase of the jQuery involved.

http://i46.tinypic.com/2mzxflu.jpg

Have seen some similar questions on here but nothing exactly like this. Could someone explain or at least point me in the right direction?

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41762459/187650

Answer (score 5):

I ended up stumbling across this issue and added a CSS class for it:

```
.collapse-non-md {
    height: 0;
    display: none;
}
.collapse-non-md.collapsing {
    display: block;
}

@media (min-width: 992px) {
    .collapse-non-md {
        height: auto;
        display: block;
    }
}
```

Then I set the class of the element I wanted collapsed on screens below medium to `collapse-non-md` and voila, it's collapsed on small browsers and open on medium ones. It can still be opened and closed the normal way (the `.in` class overrides `.collapse-non-md`).

Comment: nice, this came in handy, thanksy! I took out the height css though because it was giving strange results.

Comment: Glad I could help. I can't remember exactly what `height` was for now, it might have been for a sliding animation.

Answer (score 1):

A quick and dirty way: would be to write code for the full size sidebar that you want to show on desktop screens and separate markup for the collapsed sidebar to show on mobile devices.

Then to chose when to display either version of the sidebar use the [classes provided by bootstrap](http://twitter.github.com/bootstrap/scaffolding.html#responsive) for hiding and showing content based on media queries.

Collapsed sidebar: `.hidden-desktop .hidden-tablet .visible-phone`

Full sidebar: `hidden-phone .visible-tablet .visible-desktop`

Comment: Thanks, that would work. But I was hoping to find a solution without having to have 2 sidebars. I'm sure it's possible.

Answer (score 0):

I had the same problem using Bootstrap V3. I followed the tutorial on the official documentation, but couldn't get the sidebar to collapse by default on mobiles.

This comes from a bug in Bootstrap V3 source files (custom version generated on 2013/09/05). Just load the following CSS right after the original bootstrap.css :

```
.collapse{display:none}.collapse.in{display:block}.collapsing{position:relative;height:0;overflow:hidden;-webkit-transition:height .35s ease;transition:height .35s ease}
@media screen and (min-width:768px){.nav-collapse.collapse{display:block!important;height:auto!important;overflow:visible!important}}
```

(Those styles come from a previous version of the original Bootstrap V3 source).

Otherwise, my only mistake was to initialize the collapse plug-in in my HTML page. So if you've got something like this in your HTML source code :

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function(){
        $('.collapse').collapse();
    });
</script>
```

...then just remove it and the collapse plug-in will work like a charm.