# Collapse DIV only on Mobile View - Bootstrap 3

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have a sidebar search parameters. I want to make collapse function on this DIV only on Mobile device. Using Bootstrap 3 - Latest version.

Here is the HTML Markup.

```
<div class="col-md-3 col-sm-4 SearchParameters">
            <h4 data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#search">Location</h4>
            <div class="col-md-12 sCheck no-gutter collapse" id="search">
                <h5>Lahore (254)</h5>
                <div class="col-md-12">
                    <form role="form">
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="ModelTown">
                            <label for="ModelTown">Model Town</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="DHA">
                            <label for="DHA">DHA</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="CG">
                            <label for="CG">Cavalry Ground</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Gulberg">
                            <label for="Gulberg">Gulberg</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Samnabad">
                            <label for="Samnabad">Samnabad</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="AIT">
                            <label for="AIT">Allama Iqbal Town</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="GardenTown">
                            <label for="GardenTown">Garden Town</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="Township">
                            <label for="Township">Township</label>
                        </div>
                        <div class="checkbox checkbox-primary">
                            <input type="checkbox" id="FaisalTown">
                            <label for="FaisalTown">Faisal Town</label>
                        </div>
                        <a href="#">20 more locations</a>
                    </form>
                </div><!-- form-group -->
                <div class="clearfix"></div>
                <h5 class="second">Availability</h5>

                <div class="col-md-12 SelectDays">
                    <a href="#" class="Day">M</a>
                    <a href="#" class="Day">T</a>
                    <a href="#" class="Day active">W</a>
                    <a href="#" class="Day">Th</a>
                    <a href="#" class="Day">F</a>
                    <a href="#" class="Day">S</a>
                    <a href="#" class="Day">SU</a>
                </div><!-- SelectDays -->

                <div class="col-md-12 TimeSet">
                    <!-- timeFunction -->
                </div><!-- TimeSet -->

            </div><!-- col-md-12 -->
        </div><!-- SearchParameters -->
```

The SearchParameters DIV I use to give styling to the code.

Note : I want to collapse "SearchParameters" div only on mobile and opened it with a button.. There should be only 1 div.  I can hide this div and show another div which is visible on mobile devices but that's not a good approach. I want to collapse this div and show it on button click only on mobile devices.

Comment: Want to hide the `div`?

Comment: I want to collapse "SearchParameters" div only on mobile and opened it with a button.

Answer (score 28, accepted):

You could do it this way:

```
<button class="visible-xs" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#SearchParameters">Toggle it</button>

<div class="hidden-xs col-md-3 col-sm-4 SearchParameters" id="SearchParameters">
...
```

CSS:

```
#SearchParameters.in,
#SearchParameters.collapsing {
    display: block!important;
}
```

Comment: This solution doesn't work in Bootstrap 3.3.5, using `hidden-xs` means that the collapsible area doesn't expand at all

Comment: @Rudi css fixed it! Works

Comment: This worked well for me but I found if I was at XS clicked to collapse then uncollapse, then changed the screen width above XS that it wasn't visible, so I added a media query to force it always visible above a breakpoint eg. `@media screen and (min-width:768px) { #SearchParameters{  display: block!important;visibility:visible!important; } }`

Comment: Clean solution. I used the answer by Rudi together with the addendum by johna for good measure.

Answer (score 13):

Since the "in" class is what defines the collapsible element as open, removing it on mobile causes it to start out collapsed.

E.g.

```
<button data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapsible">Show/Hide</button>
<div class="collapse in" id="collapsible">
    Content Here.
</div>
<div class="visible-xs" id="xs-check"></div>
<script>
if( $("#xs-check").is(":visible") )
    $("#collapsible").removeClass("in");
</script>
```

Comment: I opted for doing it the other way around (adding the `in` class if the check was hidden).

Comment: I used this method but used the default bootstrap javascript like so:
`if($("#visible-check").is(":visible")) {   $("#collapsible").collapse('show');  } else { $("#collapsible").collapse('hide');  }`   Benefit is the classes being added and removed is automatic. [Bootstrap 3 reference](https://getbootstrap.com/docs/3.3/javascript/#collapse-options)

Comment: Thanks for that, I didn't know that function exists and it does seem a better option than adding classes manually.

Answer (score 2):

CSS-only method. Also works on Bootstrap 4.

```css
@media (min-width: 768px) {
  .collapse.dont-collapse-sm {
    display: block;
    height: auto !important;
    visibility: visible;
  }
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  
  <button class="btn btn-primary hidden visible-xs" type="button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseExample" aria-expanded="false" aria-controls="collapseExample">
    Collapse Button
  </button>
  
  <div class="collapse dont-collapse-sm" id="collapseExample">
    <div class="well">
      Collapse Panel
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```

[source](https://codepen.io/glebkema/pen/xryaKK)

Answer (score 0):

Why not using the window.matchMedia?

For simplicity I've created an example based on Andrew Dinmore. **It doesn't need the extra empty div** to check whether something is visible or not.

```
<button class="btn btn-default btn-block visible-xs hidden-sm hidden-md hidden-lg" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#Foo">Toggle</button>

<div id="Foo" class="collapse in">
  <!-- fancy content here -->
</div>

<script type="text/javascript">
    $(document).ready(function () {
      if (matchMedia) {
        var mq = window.matchMedia("(max-width: 768px)");
        mq.addListener(WidthChange);
        WidthChange(mq);
      }

      function WidthChange(mq) {
        if (mq.matches) {
          $("#Foo").removeClass("in");
        }
      }
    });
  </script>
```

enjoy! ;-)

Comment: Just to note, in case it interests anyone, there are a couple of reasons I usually check against element visibility, rather than using matchMedia. The first, though almost completely irrelevant now, is that IE<10 doesn't support it. The main reason, however, is that very few projects (certainly that I've worked on) are set up to enable values to be shared between JavaScript and CSS, which can lead to issues if a break-point needs to be tweaked and somebody doesn't realise. There are plenty of ways to do so with any decent build system, but it's so rarely needed nobody seems to bother.

Comment: Of course, there's nothing wrong with using matchMedia per say; it's actually a more technically valid way of doing the job. If the build process isn't set up to share break-point values, though, I don't think an extra couple of bytes is anything to worry about for piece of mind, certainly not with the amount of data required for the average page these days.

Answer (score 0):

Similiar to Rudy's solution, I found the following worked well for my needs, for **Bootstrap 4.6** & **Razor** (**Blazor WASM**) :

```
@media (min-width: 641px) {
  .collapse.collapse-show-xs {
      display: block !important;
  }
}
```

Usage:

```
<div class="collapse collapse-show-xs @NavMenuCssClass" @onclick="ToggleNavMenu">
    <ul class="nav flex-column">
        <li class="nav-item px-3">
            <NavLink class="nav-link" href="" Match="NavLinkMatch.All">
                <span class="oi oi-home" aria-hidden="true"></span> Home
            </NavLink>
        </li>
```

When I upgraded the version of bootstrap for Blazorize, I noticed my sidebar was not showing anymore.  Now it's doing what I want, which is that it never hides when at least meeting xs screen size, and can be hidden when below.