# When I open website on mobile bootstrap navbar is not collapse

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, twitter-bootstrap, jquery-mobile-navbar

This situation is strange. When I open my website (built on bootstrap) on small screens navbar is visible, but it should be collapse. When I click on button to collapse, it is still visible, when I click second time it is collapse just now. And since that it works good. But when I reload page, I still have this issue.

```
       <div class=container>                       
      <!--MENU-->
<nav  style="border-bottom:1px solid #000;">
            <div class="navbar-header">
        <button type="button" class="navbar-toggle collapsed menu_button" data-toggle="collapse" data-target=".nbar" aria-expanded="false">
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
          <span class="icon-bar"></span>
        </button>
    </div>
      <div class="container nbar">
        <ul class="nav nav-justified">
          <li><a href=#>o nas</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>galeria</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>blog</a></li>
          <li><a href=#>kontakt</a></li>
        </ul>
      </div>
</nav>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add the class `collapse in` classes to your `nav` element. This way it will still be visible on mobile but the button will work like expected. If you only apply `collapse` as class and set the `aria-expanded` to `false` it will not be visible on mobile (but most likely also not in normal view).

```
<div class="container nbar collapse in" aria-expanded="true">
     <ul class="nav nav-justified">
         <!-- li's here -->  
     </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you. But is there any simple solution to make visible menu on desktop when on mobile is hidden?

Comment: Check the answer here: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/28086811/collapse-div-only-on-mobile-view-bootstrap-3