# Bootstrap collapse panel not working on mobile

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

Hi, I'm tyring to make a mobile version of a website. I used collapse panel from Bootstrap so the user can view specified content easily. Everything works perfectly in desktop mode, but when I go in mobile, if I toggle the collapse div, the fonts and the content shrinks for a reason I don't understand. I tried different version of imports (bootstrap, jquery) and I read the existing related problems but I didn't find any answer so far. 
Here's a picture of the current behavior of the code (tested on a real phone):
https://i.stack.imgur.com/2y0x0.jpg

Here's the code:

```
<html lang="en">
 <head>
    <!-- STYLE IMPORT -->
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/bootstrap/css/bootstrap.min.css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="../libs/font-awesome/css/font-awesome.min.css">
    <link href='https://fonts.googleapis.com/css?family=Montserrat:400,700' rel='stylesheet' type='text/css'>
    <link rel="icon" type="image/png" href="../img/brand-image.png" />
    <!-- SCRIPT IMPORT -->

    <style>
.panel-heading a:after {
    font-family:'Glyphicons Halflings';
    content:"\e114";
    float: right;
    color: grey;
}
.panel-heading a.collapsed:after {
    content:"\e080";
}
    </style>
</head>
<body>
    <div class="fluid-container">
<div class="panel panel-default">
    <div class="panel-heading"><a data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" href="#collapseOne">Panel 1</a></div>
    <div id="collapseOne" class="panel-collapse collapse in">
        <div class="panel-body">
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-check" style="padding-right:25px"></i> Lorem Ipsum</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit. Ut tempor faucibus lacus in lacinia. Mauris sed sem nibh. In sem sapien, aliquam et placerat vitae, rutrum eget nunc. Maecenas consequat molestie fringilla. Nunc non pellentesque augue. Fusce egestas, urna pellentesque aliquam interdum, mi enim efficitur sem, et pretium orci diam eu ipsum. Vestibulum lobortis pellentesque massa sed gravida. Cum sociis natoque penatibus et magnis dis parturient montes, nascetur ridiculus mus. Pellentesque tortor mi, consectetur at molestie sit amet, aliquet eu felis. Integer euismod rhoncus egestas. Donec porta ligula vel libero maximus molestie. Fusce porttitor dictum magna vitae maximus. Cras pulvinar consectetur orci, ac tincidunt libero condimentum nec. Sed molestie lacinia neque sed sollicitudin.        
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="panel panel-primary">
                <div class="panel-heading"><i class="fa fa-check" style="padding-right:25px"></i> Morbi quis magna</div>
                <div class="panel-body">
    Morbi quis magna scelerisque, egestas leo id, sodales lectus. Aliquam vel commodo leo. Vestibulum imperdiet maximus felis, quis ullamcorper tellus sodales in. Nunc aliquet, lectus a maximus pellentesque, dolor neque tempor sem, vitae dignissim enim neque et arcu. Nullam at sagittis tortor, sed imperdiet turpis. Quisque non leo sollicitudin, tincidunt felis a, fringilla tellus. Phasellus ipsum lorem, sodales non dolor nec, viverra rutrum magna. Phasellus quam purus, efficitur ac sodales ac, pretium ac tellus. Aenean pulvinar felis sollicitudin tellus bibendum, ac vestibulum nulla facilisis. Mauris maximus, dui in gravida molestie, tellus nisl convallis ex, ut fermentum orci odio at mauris. Donec et erat eget diam ultrices auctor et vitae felis. Nullam et arcu ligula. Proin nec tristique dui, ut luctus velit.
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="fluid-container">
                 <button type="button" class="btn btn-primary" style="width:100%;font-size:20pt;padding:20px" data-toggle="collapse" data-target="#collapseOne" href="#collapseOne"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-chevron-up" aria-hidden="true"></span></button>
            </div>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
</div>
  <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery.js"></script>
    <!-- Bootstrap JavaScript -->
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.1.1/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: Other than the fix I mentioned below, as an improvement: you can add .panel-heading a { display: block; } to your css. And that will make the entire panel-heading clickable. Which is more sufficient for mobile User experience. And please make sure to vote and accept the answer it fixed your issue. Thanks!

Comment: see: http://stackoverflow.com/a/41762459/187650

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Defining your `viewport` to `device-width` is important, when you do responsive web development.

Add this to the head section:

```
<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
```

*You can find the bootstrap bioler template here: http://getbootstrap.com/getting-started/*

Comment: It fixed my problem! Thank you!

Comment: You are welcome. Please click on the tick mark on left, if this solved your issue. And please do vote the answer. Thanks!

Comment: I ticked the answer but I can't vote it yet since I don't have 15 reputation. I will vote it when I can. :)

Comment: No worries, Thanks a lot. :)